# Extension methods in c# how to assign value to the parent variable i.e the "this" variable

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a code for extension method which looks something line

```
parent class
{
   int i = 9; // the value was i was 9;
   i = i.Add(2); // here 9 + 2
   Console.WriteLine(i); // it is printing 11
}

extension class
{
   public static int Add(this int firstInteger, int secondInteger)
   {
      return (firstInteger + secondInteger);
   }
}
```

This is the extension class I have but what I need is

```
parent class
{
   int i = 9;              // the value was i was 9;
   i.Add(2);              // here 9 + 2
   Console.WriteLine(i); // it has to print 11
}
```

I'm not finding a way to do this please recommend a solution.

Comment: `ref` modifier? Damned you guys are really fast.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Just use i += 2;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, I'd strongly advise you *not* to do this. It's very counterintuitive.

But as of C# 7.2, this *is* possible - only for value types - using `ref` extension methods. Just change the first parameter to have the `ref` modifier, and assign to it:

```cs
using System;

public static class Int32Extensions
{
    public static void Add(ref this int x, int y)
    {
        x = x + y;
    }

}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int i = 9;
        i.Add(2);
        Console.WriteLine(i); // 11
    }
}
```

The `i.Add(2)` call is implicitly:

```
Int32Extensions.Add(ref i, 2);
```

It will fail if you try to call it on something that isn't a variable.

But this will be really surprising behavior for many C# developers, as the `ref` is implicit. It also isn't valid for reference types.

Comment: *The parameter modifier 'ref' cannot be used with 'this' *

Comment: @GarudaPrasadK: That would suggest you're not using C# 7.2. First make sure you're using a recent version Visual Studio (or whatever you're using to build); then make sure you've got C# 7.2 or higher selected.